# How to draw a monochrome image, then "dump" it to a vector with wxWidgets and C++?

Tags: c++, vector, wxwidgets

I'm making a program that requires an interface to draw in a 20x20 monochrome grid, then "dump" that grid to a boolean vector.

Currently I'm programming it with C++ and wxWidgets, but haven't found a way to create a grid to draw on, much less to "dump" said grid to a vector. Is there a way to do it with wxWidgets, or should I use a different system (e.g. GTK)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the classes in the [wxDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html) hierarchy.

Comment: The transformation matrix seems interesting, I will check its documentation. Remember that I'm still a total noob on everything GUI (most of my programs are command-line-based), so please be patient.